# Statistics for calls to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, usage-statistics

is there any way to find out statistics for calls to stored procedure on SQL Server?

I am looking for following information:

1. Date and time when stored procedure was called
2. Who called stored procedure (username)
3. I want to have above information even if user received error message "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_name', database 'db_name', schema 'schema_name'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SQL Server does not maintain such information.
You have to setup one of following methods to gather it:

- SQL Audit
- Extended events
- SQL Trace

Example of SQL Audit for such task:

```
-- step 1:
USE [master]
GO
CREATE SERVER AUDIT [SrvAudit_sp_execution]
TO FILE 
( FILEPATH = N'E:\DBA_Audit'
 ,MAXSIZE = 20 MB
 ,MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 50
 ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
)
WITH
( QUEUE_DELAY = 1000  -- equal to 1 second
 ,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE
)
GO

-- step 2: 
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [DBAudit_sp_execution]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [SrvAudit_sp_execution]
GO

-- step 3: 
ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [DBAudit_sp_execution]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [SrvAudit_sp_execution]
    ADD (EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.proc1 BY [public]) ;

-- step 4:
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [SrvAudit_sp_execution]   WITH (STATE = ON);

USE [_DemoDB]    
ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [DBAudit_sp_execution]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [SrvAudit_sp_execution] WITH (STATE = ON);
```

Audit data can be further viewed in SSMS or queried via:  `sys.fn_get_audit_file`

References:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3259/several-methods-to-collect-sql-server-stored-procedure-execution-history/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Also Reference link was very useful. Thank you.